# Removing Git history as a result of adding wrong remote repo

Tags: git

Looking for a bit of help with Git if possible. I'm new to Git and trying to learn so bear with me ;)

To cut a long story short I have two remote repositories set up on two different servers. I had one set up fine but when adding the second one I accidentally added a repo from an existing project.

I then fetched from this second, wrong repo and got all the commits pulled in. I removed this incorrect remote repo but the commits still exist in the tree :-S There are all my genuine commits at the top, then a break, then all the incorrect ones.

Is there anyway I can remove all these commits from my commit history as I would like to keep my tree as clean as possible?

Any help would be appreciated on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show which output of what command show the stray commits? It appears to be unclear as to what you have done. As you might expect, that has quite some influence on what you should do to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Would a `git reset --hard` to the commit before the wrong pull do? If `hash1` was the commit before the "break" you can do `git reset --hard hash1`

If by top you mean your commits are after these wrong commits or if these commits are strewn across your history, I would suggest `git rebase -i` and remove the commits from the wrong pull.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you need to do something like this:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

This will bring up a text editor showing the last five commits. Just remove the ones you don't want from the list and save. git will update the index, removing the commits that you don't want.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. In what way does this not answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

First, remove any local branches you may have checked out from the incorrect remote with `git branch -d branchname` (potentially with `-D` if it complains about it not being merged into master, but use this with caution).

Next, after you've removed the remote you'll need to remove the remote branches from your repo with `git fetch --prune`.

Finally, you can use `git gc` to remove the orphaned object references that were left behind.

Answer (score -1):

You'd simply do a

```
git gc
```

after removing the remote.

If you had any local refs pointing at the wrong branches, remove them first.

Also, note that references are kept for safety in reflogs and as dangling commits. These normally expire in due time, but if you wish, you can speed it up:

```
git gc --aggressive --prune=tomorrow
```

Do this only if you are sure you won't need to recover anything that you accidentally deleted

Comment: -1 - I don't think the OP is talking about garbage collection. It is about commits in the branch that were pulled in.

Comment: @manojlds: you seem to be assuming that he somehow managed to merge that into an unrelated branch. That would be a very hard thing to do. Perhaps you are right. I, for me, am assuming that `git log --all` still shows the unwanted commits from the unrelated branch(es). Let's ask to OP?